# Print File Info in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to print the list of all files along with the information about them like created, updated and size. Currently, I use

```
$files = File::allFiles('downloads');
```

But, this just gives me the filename. Is there a better way or is there any property for the same thing that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation. If you really want complete info for each file. 
You can try something like this

```
$files = Request::allFiles()

$fullInfo = [];
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $fullInfo[$file] = UploadedFile::createFromBase($file)
}
```

Ref: [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L429) line 429 to 455

Edit:
Sorry my bad even **UploadedFile::createFromBase** will return object

I think we don't have option in laravel to dump every properties of file. You can access each property by calling the functions like `getClientOriginalName`.

Or try native method $_FILES to

$files = $request->file('file');

foreach ($files as $file) {
   $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
}

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I can use this to get the size, create time and all other info?